# Need to center hero arrow in responsive design

Tags: html, css

I am working with a landing page that has a blue hero arrow pointing down in the content areas. I want to make it center align whenever the user minimizes the browser window size, but I cannot seem to do it with my current setup.

```css
    * {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    body {
    width: 1024;
    border-size: 3px;
    border-color: gray;
     }
    
    /*Blue header*/
    
    
    .whiteheadline {
        font-size: 48px;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .header-rectangle { 
        background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 143px;
        width: 1024px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #header-bg {
    background-image: url(http://ppc-genius.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sliceimage.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:426px;
    width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow:auto;
    }
    
    /*CTA Rectangle and form*/
    
    #cta-rectangle {
      background-color: rgb(224, 223, 223);
      box-shadow: 0px 9px 11.18px 1.82px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
      position: relative;
      width: 451px;
      height: 334px;
      z-index: 2;
      margin: 40px auto;
    }
    
    /*Hero separator and testimonial text*/
    
    .hero {  
     position:relative;
     background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
     height:128px;
     width:1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    
    }
    
    .hero:after {
     content:'';
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: solid 50px rgb(104, 115, 251);
        border-left: solid 50px transparent;
        border-right: solid 50px transparent;
    }
    
    .hero-quote {
      font-size: 26px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      font-style: italic;
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      width: 989px;
      height: 88px;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    
    /*Body content and images*/
    
    .body-container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
     }
    
    .body-container h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-align: left;
      position: absolute;
      width: 548px;
      height: 37px;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
     
     .text-container-1 {
     max-width: 544px;
      }
      
     .text-container-1 p {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-align: left;
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-left: 4px;
    }
    
    /*Check marks and header*/
    
    .check-mark-header {
      background-color: rgb(224, 223, 223);
      position: relative;
      width: 907px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .check-mark-header h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-align: left;
      position: absolute;
      width: 548px;
      height: 37px;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="generator" content="Webinar Event Landing Page by Eric Conklin">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Event Lander</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <!--Blue Header-->
      <div class="header-rectangle">
          <h1 class="whiteheadline">Join Us for a Free Webinar!</h1>
      </div>
      <!--Header image and form-->
      <div id="header-bg" align="center">
          <div id="cta-rectangle">
          <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!--Hero-->
      <div class="hero">
          <h1 class="hero-quote">“I can’t thank you enough for your coaching and support. My business has never been more profitable or easier to manage. Thank you!” <br> -Jim Smith</h1>
      </div>
      
      <!--Section for content-->
      <section class = "body-container">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/jane.png" />
           </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
             <div class="text-container-1">
                  <h1>Hello! My Name is Jane Smith!</h1><br><br>
            <p>I’m an experienced and certified AdWords professional. I lead a monthly mastermind group of like-minded business owners and consultants. We use webinars to teach the principals of campaign development, including keyword research, split-testing, tracking, reporting and optimization.</p><br>
            <p>Going it alone is rough and boring. We lead these webinars as a free training and networking opportunity to help like-minded individuals achieve sucess in their busineses and see results like never before.</p><br>
            <p>Not only does this give me the opportunity to teach, it also gives me the opportunity to learn by hearing your story, learning about your business and helping share amazing ideas with fellow entrepreneurs.</p><br>
          </div>
              </div>
             </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
      <!--Checkboxes and lower page content-->
      <section class="checkmarks">
          <div class="check-mark-header" align="center">
            <h1>Ready to Get Started? Here's What's Included</h1>
         
          </div>
      </section>
      
       <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Any tips to help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues you'll need to overcome but the basic idea is to set the `:after` arrow to `left: 50%` to center it on the page and then use negative margin to shift it back by half its width. Here are the changes.

```
.hero {     
    width:100%;
}

.hero:after {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xf9Lexkq/

Answer (score 0):

Remove most of the explicit widths. Wrap your content in a container, and center your background image.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
            <!--Blue Header-->
    <div class="header-rectangle">
        <h1 class="whiteheadline">Join Us for a Free Webinar!</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Header image and form-->
    <div id="header-bg" align="center">
        <div id="cta-rectangle">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Hero-->
        <div class="hero">
            <h1 class="hero-quote">“I can’t thank you enough for your coaching and support. My business has never been more profitable or easier to manage. Thank you!” <br> -Jim Smith</h1>
        </div>

    <!--Section for content-->
    <section class="body-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/jane.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="text-container-1">
                        <h1>Hello! My Name is Jane Smith!</h1><br><br>
                        <p>I’m an experienced and certified AdWords professional. I lead a monthly mastermind group of like-minded business owners and consultants. We use webinars to teach the principals of campaign development, including keyword research, split-testing, tracking, reporting and optimization.</p><br>
                        <p>Going it alone is rough and boring. We lead these webinars as a free training and networking opportunity to help like-minded individuals achieve sucess in their busineses and see results like never before.</p><br>
                        <p>Not only does this give me the opportunity to teach, it also gives me the opportunity to learn by hearing your story, learning about your business and helping share amazing ideas with fellow entrepreneurs.</p><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--Checkboxes and lower page content-->
    <section class="checkmarks">
        <div class="check-mark-header" align="center">
            <h1>Ready to Get Started? Here's What's Included</h1>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
border-size: 3px;
border-color: gray;
 }

/*Blue header*/


.whiteheadline {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header-rectangle { 
    background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 143px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header-bg {
background-image: url(http://ppc-genius.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sliceimage.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:426px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 1;
overflow:auto;
}

/*CTA Rectangle and form*/

#cta-rectangle {
  background-color: rgb(224, 223, 223);
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 11.18px 1.82px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  position: relative;
  width: 451px;
  height: 334px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

/*Hero separator and testimonial text*/

.hero {     
    position:relative;
    background-color: rgb(104, 115, 251);
    height:128px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;

}

.hero:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px rgb(104, 115, 251);
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}

.hero-quote {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 88px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

/*Body content and images*/

.body-container {

margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 60px;
 }

.body-container h1 {
font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 37px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .text-container-1 {
 max-width: 544px;
  }

 .text-container-1 p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

/*Check marks and header*/

.check-mark-header {
  background-color: rgb(224, 223, 223);
  position: relative;

  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.check-mark-header h1 {
font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;

  height: 37px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: Okay, problem is I want to have a max width for the page overall, so this doesn't work. It makes it a full width page, which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you modify it centers it within the body that has a predetermined width as above?

Comment: you are using bootstrap and wrapping things in the `container` class will contain it to the breakpoint size. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: You will also need something like `background-position-x: center;` on the header background if you want to center the image.